# MVC 6 streaming pdf content to a browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, streaming

In my new project (MCV 6/Core 2) I use `ITextSharp` to generate dynamic pdf files. These files are not stored on the server or the network, so the location/path doesn't exist.

I need to find a way to display these files in a browser without downloading.

Streaming a byte array is the only option that comes to my mind.

I did experiment with `embed/object` tags and set the src to the stream. It works in Chrome/Firefox but not in Edge/IE. But even with Chrome/Firefox, I wasn't able to find a way to set a filename in a stream or in the view html/razor.

Does anyone have any suggestions, using MVC 6, how to display a pdf file in all browsers without downloading?

Comment: Thanks for the well researched question